# How to Ignore errors in Dataframe to_sql method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-to-sql

I am using Pandas DataFrame.to_SQL() to insert data from dataframe to table. Nothing gets loaded if even a single record has loading issues, for example: if a integer column has character data in one row or date format is not valid in one record etc.

How to ignore these errors? I want to load atleast the data which is valid instead of not loading anything at all in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for Python's `try` and `except` block.

> Python executes code following the try statement as a “normal” part of the program. The code that follows the except statement is the program’s response to any exceptions in the preceding try clause. ([Source](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/#the-try-and-except-block-handling-exceptions))

[image]

For your specific use case, as you want to use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), the following should do the work

```
def insert_data(df, table_name): # df is a dataframe, table_name is a string
    try: # if there are errors, ignore them and load the valid data
        df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False) # if_exists='append' means that if the table already exists, it will append the new data to the existing table
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # print the error
        df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=1000) # chunksize=1000 means that the data will be loaded in chunks of 1000 rows
```